# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.config.experimental' has no attribute 'set_lms_enabled'

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I wanted to use LMS for my deep learning project, and I used the code for this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.experimental.set_lms_enabled(True)
```

from this [IBM GitHub link](https://github.com/IBM/tensorflow-large-model-support). But I get the mentioned error.

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.config.experimental' has no attribute 'set_lms_enabled'
```

I tried it in colab notebook, which uses tensorflow 2.2. Should I downgrade it? How else do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

according to [TensorFlow Large Model Support github page](https://github.com/IBM/tensorflow-large-model-support):

> TFLMS is built into the tensorflow-gpu **conda** package so it is installed by default when you install the GPU enabled TensorFlow from WML CE.

so you need to install anaconda and install TensorFlow from WML CE by conda package manager.
to install anaconda follow anaconda official document page by this link:
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/